# Scraping html id with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having issues scraping the html IDs off of the below html file, because there are 2 lines of code that do not have any ID under `14 Jun 2020`, meaning that there are no further appointment slots after`8.15am on 14 June`, appointments resume on 15 June.

```
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped no-background clear-padding-first-child available-slots-mobile main-table clone">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="14%" class="text-left nowrap fixed-side">Session Date</th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>1</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>2</b>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tr-border-bottom">
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('13 Jun 2020');">13 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Saturday
            </th>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217464_1_13/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('14 Jun 2020');">13 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Sunday
            </th>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217482_1_14/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('15 Jun 2020');">15 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Monday
            </th>

            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217506_1_15/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have come up with the below code, but only the html IDs of the appointments up till the `8.15am 14th June 2020 slot` will be printed. I then encounter a **TypeError (NoneType object is not iterable)** after the ID of the `8.15am 14 June` slot has been printed, and no IDs of the 15th June slots are printed.

```
for slots in soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"}):
    tags = slots.find("a")
    for IDS in tags:
        IDS = tags.attrs["id"]
    print (IDS)
```

I also tried exception handling here, but I encounter a syntax error (and i'm not too sure what i've done wrong exactly).

```
for slots in soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"}):
    tags = slots.find("a")
    for IDS in tags:
        try:
            IDS = tags.attrs["id"]
        except TypeError:
            else:
            print (IDS)
```

Comment: check the answer below , you missed up the css selectors and the exception handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the tag is there a tag with `id` attribute then print that.

```
data='''<table class="table table-borderless table-striped no-background clear-padding-first-child available-slots-mobile main-table clone">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="14%" class="text-left nowrap fixed-side">Session Date</th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>1</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>2</b>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tr-border-bottom">
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('13 Jun 2020');">13 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Saturday
            </th>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217464_1_13/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('14 Jun 2020');">13 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Sunday
            </th>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217482_1_14/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">


                                             8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('15 Jun 2020');">15 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Monday
            </th>

            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217506_1_15/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

for slots in soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"}):
    tag= slots.find("a",id=True)
    if tag:
        print(tag.attrs["id"])
```

---

You can achieve the same using single css selector.

```
for slots in soup.select('.pb-15.text-center>a[id]'):
    if slots:
        print(slots.attrs["id"])
```

**Output**:

```
1217464_1_13/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
1217482_1_14/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
1217506_1_15/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
```

---

**Update**

```
for slots in soup.findAll(attrs={"class" : "pb-15 text-center"}):
    tag= slots.find("a",attrs={"id",True})
    if tag:
        print(tag.attrs["id"])
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your input! unfortunately the id = True part doesn't seem to work, but the css selector does. i would like to know how to make my code work without the use of the css selector though, would you happen to have any ideas apart from using id = True? thanks!

Comment: @maz : I am getting output in both cases.However updated one more option with  `tag= slots.find("a",attrs={"id",True})` let me know how this goes. I am getting output for all 3 options.

Comment: hi, it works for me! i may have messed up accidentally haha, thank you so much! could I ask what the purpose of the ```if tag:``` is?

Comment: Verifying if its having anchor tag with id attribute then get the ID value.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''
<table class="table table-borderless table-striped no-background clear-padding-first-child available-slots-mobile main-table clone">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="14%" class="text-left nowrap fixed-side">Session Date</th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>1</b>
            </th>
            <th width="14%" class="text-center">
                <b>2</b>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tr-border-bottom">
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('13 Jun 2020');">13 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Saturday
            </th>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217464_1_13/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('14 Jun 2020');">13 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Sunday
            </th>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217482_1_14/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
            <td class="pb-15 text-center"><span class="c-gray">n/a</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="pb-15 text-left fixed-side">
                <a href="javascript:changeDate('15 Jun 2020');">15 Jun 2020</a>
                <br> Monday
            </th>

            <td class="pb-15 text-center">
                <a href="#" id="1217506_1_15/6/2020 12:00:00 AM" class="slotBooking">
                                                                        8:15 AM ✔
                                                                    </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup  = bs(html, 'html.parser')
slots = soup.select("td[class='pb-15 text-center'] a")
for slot in slots:
        #slot.attrs is a dictionary so you can avoid NoneType Expection using .get method 
        #slot_id = slot.attrs.get("id",'') this will return '' if there is no id attribute in the tag
        slot_id = slot.attrs.get("id",'')
        print(slot_id)
```

Output:

```
1217464_1_13/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
1217482_1_14/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
1217506_1_15/6/2020 12:00:00 AM
```